# SQL Query Comparison with UNION Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

We the help of colleagues I have compiled the following sql code to compare and strip out records that appear two tables.

```
WITH cmn AS 
(
    SELECT a.CDC_TYPE
    FROM tabled a 
    INNER JOIN tablee b ON a.COUNTRY_ID = b.COUNTRY_ID
                        AND a.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT = b.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT 
                        AND a.CDC_TYPE = 'U'
)
SELECT 
    1 AS is_deleted, 
    a.* 
FROM
    tabled a 
INNER JOIN 
    cmn ON a.CDC_TYPE = cmn.CDC_TYPE 

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
    0 AS is_deleted, 
    b.* 
FROM
    tablee b 
INNER JOIN 
    cmn ON b.CDC_TYPE = cmn.CDC_TYPE
```

The the sample data is from the following tables:

[image: tabled]

[image: tablee]

The expected result from the query should simply look like:

[image: correctout]

However, the output looks like the following:

[image: incorrectoutput]

Can someone let me know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Join condtition does not make any sense `ON a.CDC_TYPE = cmn.CDC_TYPE ` => `'U' = 'U'` => cross join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write the query as:

```
; with cmn as 
  ( SELECT a.CDC_TYPE,
           a. PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT, --Add these also in CTE result set 
           a.COUNTRY_ID --Add these also in CTE result set 
    FROM    a  
    INNER JOIN  b  
    ON a.COUNTRY_ID = b.COUNTRY_ID 
    AND a.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT = b.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT  
    AND a.CDC_TYPE = 'U'
    )
 SELECT 1 AS is_deleted, 
        a.*  
 FROM    a  
 INNER JOIN cmn  
 ON a.CDC_TYPE = cmn.CDC_TYPE 
 and  a.COUNTRY_ID = cmn.COUNTRY_ID  
 AND a.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT = cmn.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT

 UNION ALL  
 SELECT 0 AS is_deleted, 
        b.*  
 FROM    b  
 INNER JOIN cmn  
 ON b.CDC_TYPE = cmn.CDC_TYPE 
 and b.COUNTRY_ID = cmn.COUNTRY_ID 
 AND b.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT = cmn.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT
```

when you return only `CDC_TYPE` 'U' from CTE and joins the value again with table a and b it actually gets multiplied with all the rows of table a and b respectively as all of them qualifies the condition `a.CDC_TYPE = cmn.CDC_TYPE`. To avoid getting all results you should include `PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT` and `COUNTRY_ID` in the CTE result set.
 [Test code here...](https://rextester.com/PTN82454)

Comment: I'm getting the following error: invalid object name 'a' ( SELECT a.CDC_TYPE, - I should mention that I'm quite a novice.

Comment: I have pasted your script exactly as-is but I keep on getting the same error:

Comment: Deepshikha, I was being silly, I inserted the tables into the code and it worked beautifully. Thanks

Comment: Deepshikha, just one last related question. At the moment, the records are based on CDC_TYPE being to 'U'. Is there any easy modification to the code to get same result if the CDC_TYPE is equal to either 'U' or 'D'? Instead of just 'U'? Once again thanks for your help

Comment: the query doesn't restrict itself to the values in attribute `CDC_TYPE` . All the records where `CDC_TYPE` , `PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT ` and `COUNTRY_ID` are same in `table a ` and `b` will come with records in table a with 1 as `is_deleted` and 0 from table b.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Sorry, I wasn't making myself clear. I have added values in CDC_TYPE of N that doesn't have corresponding match in each table for PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT and COUNTRY_ID. However, I would like for any instance of the record N in CDC_TYPE to be included in the result. I hope I'm making myself clear